Counting the total number of titles that can be granted in a descending hierarchy
The titles would follow this hierarchy;
King,
Duke,
Marquis,
Earl,
Viscount,
Baron,
Knight,
The problem being looked at is to try and solve for the total amount of titles created when each title can grant 4 single lower level titles and 16 second level lower titles, with each level lowered on the title hierarchy granting 4 times more titles until reaching the bottom of the hierarchy.
Each of the lower level titles generated by higher level titles would also follow this principle of 4x increase for every level lowered, such as a viscount granting 4 Barons and 16 knights directly and 16 knights secondarily by those 4 barons, thus adding up to 36 new titles generated for every 1 viscount created.
At the bottom I will add the amount of titles that could be granted based on title level, this would be the titles that could be granted directly and not the ones that would be generated on a secondary or tertiary basis.
I was wondering if there is a formula for this kind of problem, such as if we wanted to grant 3 or 5 titles for every level lowered on the hierarchy.
The final goal would be getting the total amount of titles granted
1 King; 4 Duke, 16 Marquis, 64 Earl, 256 Viscount, 1024 Barons, 4096 Knights
1 Duke; 4 Marquis, 16 Earl, 64 Viscount, 256 Baron, 1024 Knights
1 Marquis; 4 Earl, 16 Viscount, 64 Baron, 256 Knights
1 Earl; 4 Viscount, 16 Baron, 64 Knights
1 Viscount; 4 Baron, 16 Knights
1 Baron; 4 Knights
1 Knight

Total Titles Granted By Level (inclusive of title). Knight: 1, Baron: 5, Viscount: 37, Earl: 293, Marquis: 2,341

Duke: 18,725, King: 149796

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If $a_n$ is the number of titles at level $n$, starting with $a_0 = 1$ (the king), then I think you mean
$$ a_{n} = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n 4^k a_{n-k} $$
If so, the formula is
$$ a_n = \frac{3+4 \cdot 8^n}{7} $$
For $n = 0$ to $6$ the results are
$$  1, 5, 37, 293, 2341, 18725, 149797$$
which agrees with your "Total Titles Granted" for knight, baron, etc, except you have only $149796$ for king (maybe because the king is not "granted"?).

Thanks for the answer, that was very helpful. It was my mistake on the last one as I just forgot to add the +1 for the King title.
